# Doctrine ODM - how to set a value in my document by passing the name of the field

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I have a MongoDB Document called User. I also have the array containing all possible "updatable" fields (this is for an API where a third party can update fields in my DB by sending a request). I want to do something like:

```
$user_document->set(array($field => $value));
$document_manager->flush();
```

Where *$user_document* is the document got by FindOneBy, and *$field* and *$value* are the values from the API request. This does not work. How to manually insert value to a given field? I dont want to use setFieldName method, because there are a lot of fields and I want to keep them in an array.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem, here's the correct approach:

```
$result = $document_manager
    ->createQueryBuilder('AppBundle:User')
    ->findAndUpdate()
    ->returnNew()
    ->field($field)->set($value)
    ->field('id')->equals($given_id)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```